# Convert Survey Results into 3-Dimension Table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm attempting to convert a table of raw data into a table of summarised results with three fields in the simplest way.

The data is taken from a survey where the participant will note their location, and then answer multiple choice questions each with three possible answers.

The columns of the raw table look something like:

```
    AREA   | Q1   | Q2   | Q3   |...| Q10
    Area 1   Op1    Op1    Op3        Op2
    Area 2   Op1    Op2    Op1        Op3
    Area 1   Op1    Op3    Op1        Op3
    Area 3   Op3    Op1    Op2        Op1
```

Where the questions can be answered with multiple choice options 1 to 3, and areas can be repeated (ie, survey participant one is in Australia, participant two is in New Zealand, and participant three is also in Australia).

I'd like the output table to look something like:

```
            Question One    | Question 2      | Question 3      |...| Question 10
            Op1 | Op2 | Op3 | Op1 | Op2 | Op3 | Op1 | Op2 | Op3 |...| Op1 | Op2 | Op3 | 
    Area 1   #     3     #     #     #     #     #     #     #    #     #     #    #
    Area 2   #     #     #     #     #     #     #     #     #    #     #     #    #
    Area 3   #     #     #     #     #     #     #     #     #    #     #     #    #
```

So that the count for each response in relation to each area, question, and option is shown. For instance if three participants in area 1 answered Q1 with option 2, I'd want the value in the table to be 3, as shown above.

I've attempted to manipulate pivot tables so far, but I've not had much luck using three criteria. Without resorting to manual sorting or writing a macro to do the work for me, I'm not sure of the most efficient way to convert this data into the desired format and any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've had to do this before, I've avoided the built-in Pivot Tables and done the following:

From this data
[image: DataIn]

Concatenate the three pieces of data together in a new sheet. If, for eaxmple, I call the sheet with the original data in DataIn, I would put the following formula in a new sheet:

```
=DataIn!B$1&DataIn!$A2&DataIn!B2
```

This produces data like this:

q1Area 1Op1

Copy this formula across and down to get all the data in this new format.

I call this sheet Calculations.

[image: Calculations]

In a new sheet, put the headings

```
     Op1 Op2 Op3 Op1 Op2 Op3 Op1 Op2 Op3 etc

     q1  q1  q1  q2  q2  q2  q3  q3  q3 etc

Area 1

Area 2  

Area 3  

etc
```

Finally, enter the following formula in the cells:

```
=COUNTIF(Calculations!$A:$J,Output!B$2&Output!$A3&Output!B$1)
```

This uses the headings in the table to re-create the three codes with the previous table and counts them.

[image: Output]

Finally if you want different headings (to make it look nice), create this in another sheet and just copy the data over from the previous sheet using =B3 etc

Comment: This solution is perfect for what I'm after. Worked perfectly and was able to fit nicely into the lookup based, infinitely expandable table I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your data. If you've got the PowerQuery add-in installed (or have Excel 2016 or Excel/Office 365 subscription) then you can use PowerQuery to do this. Google "PowerQuery" and "Unpivot" and you'll turn up a whole heap of videos.

Otherwise you can use VBA such as my Unpivot routine I've previously blogged about at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/